# Can you omit an implied object?

Tags: objects

In English you can say "my friend is visiting" with the object me/us implicit. In German can you say "meine Freundin besucht" omitting the object? Or must you be explicit?

Answer (score 3):

You can't, at least not as a literal translation.

> <s>Mein Freund besucht gerade</s>

Wouldn't count as a complete sentence because *besuchen* has mandatory transitivity, thus **needs** an accusative object.

You could, however, formulate the same fact as

> Mein Freund ist [auf/zu] Besuch

with the same meaning as in English.

Comment: ...ist *zu* Besuch?

Comment: "auf Besuch" seems regional and even there much less common: http://mediawiki.ids-mannheim.de/VarGra/index.php/Auf_/_zu_Besuch

Comment: In general it depends on the verb, with a good portion of transitive verbs having an optional accusative object, for example *essen*. Sometimes these verbs are called ambitransitive, but such a label may be misleading since there seems to be a continuum between fully transitive and fully intransitive. You can also have optional dative objects, which increases the number of possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

You may get rid of the object, but you need a different verb for that to work. Idiomatic sentences are:

> Meine Freundin kommt heute. (like "arrives today") *or*
> Meine Freundin ist gerade da. (like "is currently visiting")